# Kendo-ui combobox with angularjs, not selecting option by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox, kendo-ui

I was trying to set dynamically the selected data on combobox kendo ui, but unfortunately is not working.

I did the following steps:

1. Charged all the componets kendo with data from server using $q.all;
2. Requested to server the data from specific object with id;
3. Configured the ng-model of kendo-combo-box for "item.id"

But when the id is returned, the combobox show the number id instead of description binded to this id.

This is my code:

Page:

```
<select kendo-combo-box
                    name="project"
                    k-placeholder="'Select a project'"
                    k-data-text-field="'NameProject'"
                    k-data-value-field="'IdProject'"
                    k-filter="'contains'"
                    k-auto-bind="false"
                    k-min-length="3"
                    k-data-source="projects"  
                    ng-model="item.idproject"                      
                    style="width: 100%" required></select>


 $q.all([
        Item.projects().$promise,
        Item.requests().$promise,
        Item.users().$promise
    ]).then(function (data) {
        $scope.projects = data[0];
        $scope.requests = data[1];
        $scope.users = data[2];

        $scope.id = Service.getId();
        if ($scope.id == 0 || $scope.id == null) 
            $scope.item = new Item();            
        else {
            var response = Item.get({ id: $scope.id });
            response.$promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.item = data;
                console.log(data);
            });
        }            
    });
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: it's been awhile since I've looked at angularjs, the `$promise` usage here seems kind of iffy to me.. does `Item.projects()` return a function.. or is it actually returning any array of objects? `item.idproject` doesn't seem to fit, but you stated above that you've configured it for `item.id` ( so why did you provide this snippet using `item.idproject`, is this snippet functional, where as `item.id` isn't?

Comment: what is the data structure of a `project` ?

Comment: So.. i'm usin $promise to get the end of  asynchronous function, the $q.all get the $promises to know when the all requests are finished. It was the unique way that i found to know when all requests have done. Item is a service that contains a url to my method on the backend, so, Item.projects() is returning a array of objects. The "Item.get" return a unique object that contains a property idproject, and this object is not of type project, because of that i called this object of "item" in scope.

Comment: k-data-source="projects" receive a array of project object, that contains IdProject and NameProject properties. Thanks for help me!